# How to make bot ask questions only once

Tags: chatbot, aiml

In aiml how to make bot answer questions like what is your name, your age, where do you live only once I did not understand this code

```
   <category>
<pattern>INQUIRY AGE</pattern>
    <template><srai>INQUIRY AGE <get name="age"/></srai></template>
    </category>

    <category>
<pattern>INQUIRY AGE HOW MANY</pattern>
    <template>How old are you?</template>
    </category>

    <category>
<pattern>INQUIRY AGE *</pattern>
    <template><srai>RANDOM PICKUP LINE</srai>
</template>
    </category>
```

Also from UDC

```
<random>
<li>INQUIRY AGE</li>
</random>
```

How to make bot ask these questions once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the `<random>` tag, you need to set a counter so the bot knows which question to ask and increase it each time. This will do it:

```
<category>
<pattern>ASK ME A QUESTION</pattern>
<template>
    <condition name="question">
        <li value="unknown">
            <think>
                <set name="question">1</set>
            </think>
            How old are you?
        </li>
        <li value="1">How old are you?</li>
        <li value="2">What is your name?</li>
        <li value="3">Where do you live?</li>
        <li>no more questions to ask...</li>
    </condition>
    <think>
        <set name="question">
            <map name="successor"><get name="question"/></map>
        </set>
    </think>
</template>
</category>
```

Answer (score 0):

The above code worked as expected but it gave me problem which was

"SuccessorMap could not convert to integer string"

I am using program-y, however I found a way to do this which is

```
<category>
<pattern>*</pattern> 
<template><srai>MAINBOT <star/></srai></template>
 </category>
```

Then

```
<category>
<pattern>MAINBOT *</pattern> 
<template><srai>UDC</srai></template>
 </category>
```

The UDC

```
<category>
<pattern>UDC</pattern> 
<template>
<random>
<li><srai>RANDOM PICKUP LINE</srai></li>
<li><srai>ASKNAME</srai></li>
</random>
</template> 
</category>
```

And finally

```
<category>
    <pattern>MAINBOT ASKNAME</pattern>
    <template>
        
        <condition name="name">
            <li value="unknown">What is your name?</li>
            <li><srai>UDC</srai></li>
        </condition>
        </template>
    </category>
    

    <category>
        <pattern>my name is *</pattern>
        <template><star/> is a great name <think><set name="name"><star/></set></think></template>
    </category>
```

This will make bot ask to QUESTIONS only once